# dropdownlist event

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder

I have been searching all around for a guide on event handling in flash builder 4.5. I have a dropdownlist that I'd like to activate preferably a action script function. similar to asp.net/js.

cheers!

Comment: Adobe TV has a great series that focus' on Flex SDK and Flash Builder 4.5 IDE more so than many tutorials out there. [Flex-In-A-Week](http://tv.adobe.com/show/flex-in-a-week). They go into a decent level of detail on Events. IMO the event system is Flex's saving grace.

Answer (score 0):

right out of as3 docs with some comments...

```
import fl.controls.ComboBox;
import fl.controls.Label;

var myComboBox:ComboBox = new ComboBox();
myComboBox.prompt = "Please select an item...";
myComboBox.addItem({label:"Item 1"});
myComboBox.addItem({label:"Item 2"});
myComboBox.addItem({label:"Item 3"});
myComboBox.addItem({label:"Item 4"});
myComboBox.width = 150;
myComboBox.move(10, 10);
myComboBox.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, changeHandler);  // <- ASSIGN EVENT LISTENER
addChild(myComboBox);

var myLabel:Label = new Label();
myLabel.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
myLabel.text = "selectedIndex:" + myComboBox.selectedIndex;
myLabel.move(myComboBox.x + myComboBox.width + 10, myComboBox.y);
addChild(myLabel);

function changeHandler(event:Event):void {   // <- ASSIGN FUNCTION
    myLabel.text = "selectedIndex:" + myComboBox.selectedIndex;
}
```

Also from the docs, these are the events...

**change**
Dispatched when the user changes the selection in the ComboBox component or, if the ComboBox component is editable, each time the user enters a keystroke in the text field.    ComboBox

**close**
Dispatched when the drop-down list is dismissed for any reason. ComboBox

**enter**
Dispatched if the editable property is set to true and the user presses the Enter key while typing in the editable text field.  ComboBox

**itemRollOut**
Defines the value of the type property of an itemRollOut event object.  ComboBox

**itemRollOver**
Defines the value of the type property of an itemRollOver event object. ComboBox

**open**
Dispatched when the user clicks the drop-down button to display the drop-down list. ComboBox

**scroll**
Dispatched when the user scrolls the drop-down list of the ComboBox component.  ComboBox